# Calculate Pivot D1 W1 M1

Tags: mql4

How can I calculate the Pivots D1, W1 and M1?

Can you provide me some ready to use formula?

Comment: the question is not about programming. ask at forexfactory

Comment: why not ? its mql4

Comment: you are welcome to post your questions with MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of Pivot of course. The easiest, standard pivot should look like this one: `high,low,close` are `High(_Symbol,PERIOD_D1,1)` etc.
`double values[]` is a buffer of 9 pivot values

```
     double p = (high+low+close)/3;
     values[0+4] = p;
     values[1+4] = 2*p-low;
     values[2+4] = p+high-low;
     values[3+4] = 2*p+high-2*low;
     values[4+4] = 2*p-high;
     values[5+4] = p+low-high;
     values[6+4] = 2*p+low-2*high;
     values[7+4] = p + 2 * (high-low);
     values[8+4] = p - 2 * (high-low);
```